# Can I combine HTML form button and radio input?

Tags: html

I'm not sure if this is even possible with some kind of hack, but maybe somebody knows how to achieve to combine multiple `<button>`s or even better `<input type="submit">` fields with `<input type="radio">`. In the end I want to transform the following code:

```html
<form method="post" action="/process">

  <input type="radio" name="item" value="item 1">
  <input type="radio" name="item" value="item 2">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

in something like this:

```html
<form method="post" action="/process">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Item 1">
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="item 1"/>
  </input>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit Item 2">
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="item 2"/>
  </input>

</form>
```

or maybe something like that:

```html
<form method="post" action="/process">

  <button>
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="item 1">
  </button>

  <button>
    <input type="radio" name="item" value="item 2">
  </button>

</form>
```

The goal is to have one form with multiple send-buttons, while the information which button was pressed gets also passed to the server.

Is there any chance to get this done **without JavaScript**?

Comment: “*Is there any chance to get this done without JavaScript?*” I would say this is highly unlikely, since what you’re proposing is not at all the intended use of a radio input. Can you elaborate more as to why something like `<input type="submit">` isn’t sufficient for your use case?

Comment: @esqew I need to know the value of the pressed input field as well. I'm no expert in HTML, so please be patient with me, but is this value transmitted anyway? I just haven't seen any example accessing this kind of information.

Comment: The answer below shows you how you might achieve this type of thing with the `value` property on a `<button>` element, which [the associated MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#value) also stipulate.

Comment: Well, works ;). Thank you @esqew

Comment: note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @Rob Thanks for this information. Yes, I know that, and although it is kind of anachronistic it is recommended to not put self-closing slashes into these kind of tags. But to give my idea some design I had to close the input inbetween. However, this is whether good style nor working, just the try to give a hint of what I wanted to achieve. Anyhow, thanks again for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this to solve your problem:

```
 <form method="post" action="/process">

  <button type="submit" name="item" value="item 1">
     Option 1
  </button>

  <button type="submit" name="item" value="item 2">
     Option 2
  </button>

</form>
```

Comment: You forgot to add the `name` attribute to the buttons. Therefore can not process the value because the form fields without names are not collected in form data.

Comment: Yep, with `name` it works. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, since it's marked as solved i'll edit this right now. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).